# Vuejs - Assign computed properties to data()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input field that I would like to either be blank or populate depending on the condition

- **Condition A:** new student, blank field
- **Condition B:** existing student, populated field

This data is coming from the `data()` function or a `computed:` property. For example:

```
data () {
  return {
    studentName: '', // empty student name property (/new student route)
    studentPersonality: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    getStudent // existing student object (/edit student route)
  })
}
```

My input field should either be blank if we are arriving from the `/new` student route, or populate the field with the existing student info, if we're coming from the `/edit` route.

I can populate the input field by assigning `getStudent.name` to `v-model` as shown below.

```
<input type="text" v-model="getStudent.name">
```

...and of course clear the field by instead assigning `studentName` to v-model

```
<input ... v-model="studentName">
```

**Challenge:** How can I use `getStudent.name` *IF* it exists, but fall back on the blank `studentName` data() property if `getStudent.name` does NOT exist? I have tried:

```
<input ... v-model="getStudent.name || studentName">
```

...which seemed to work, but apparently invalid and caused console errors

> 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the field to be editable if it's pre-populated?

Comment: Yes I would like the field to be editable if its pre-populated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no need to have the `input` field register to different properties in your vue component.

If you want to have a computed property that is also settable, you can define it using a set & get method.

```
computed: {
  student_name: {
    get: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.get_student.name
    },
    set: function(val) {
      this.$store.commit('set_student_name');
    }
  }
}
```

One other way is to separate the value from the input change handler in the `input element` itself, in this case you would use the getter as you've set it

```
<input type="text" :value="getStudent.name" @input="update_name($event.target.value)">
```

And lastly, if you need to really use two different properties you can set them on a `created`/`activated` hook (and answering your original question):

```
created: function() {
  this.studentName = this.getStudent
},
activated: function() {
  this.studentName = this.getStudent
}
```

You'll always need to delegate the update to the store though so I would either go with the get/set computed property, or the value/update separation