# How can i assign computed properties to data with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

In my CMS system, I can add pages. I want to also edit the existing content of these pages.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- User edits page
- Page updates in same firebase document where it was created
- Page displays new content

Right now, I have set up getter and setter in computed where getter is getting data from the firebase collection and is providing the corresponding text I want to edit, and setter will commit to the changes I do with this text.

```
  data: () => ({
    title: null,
    content: null
  }),
  computed: {
    pages: {
      get() {
        return this.pageIndex
      },
      set() {
        this.title
        this.content
      }
    }
  },
```

To update the document in firebase I am triggering this method:

```
  methods: {
    async update(id) {
      return db
        .collection('PAGES')
        .doc(id)
        .set({
          title: this.title,
          content: this.content
        })
        .then(() => {
          return this.fetchPage()
        })
    },
}
```

But it posts this in my firebase document:

```
  title: null
  content: null
```

In the console, it shows undefined. When posting the data as with array or objects, it does post whatever changes I made. But that is my problem, I do not want to post it as an object or array, I am trying to post it as field names inside a document.

The current way I am doing it results in this:

[image]

What can I change to post the updated title and content?

**Edit:**

If I do it this way it will post the data but it will post as an object and an array:

```
  data: function() {
    return {
      updatedPayload: {
        title: null,
        content: null
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pages: {
      get() {
        return this.pageIndex
      },
      set() {
        this.updatedPayload = { title: this.title, content: this.content }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async update(id) {
      //  return db.doc(`pages/${page.id}`)
      const self = this
      const pages = self.pages
      return db
        .collection('PAGES')
        .doc(id)
        .set({ pages })
        .then(() => {
          return this.fetchPage()
        })
    }
  }
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
  <tbody v-for="(page, idx) in pages" :key="page" class="">
    <b-input v-model="page.title"></b-input>
    <VueEditor v-model="page.content"></VueEditor>
  </tbody>
```

So the dilemma is, I can only update data with an object, but I can not update data with field name, as it appears.
[image]

The OP of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784139/vuejs-assign-computed-properties-to-data) is trying to achieve the same outcome as me, populate data for an input field, where as input shows existing information, and can populate new data. In my case, I need 2 inputs to populate new data, it already displays existing data from firebase.

Comment: Your problem is not on Firebase, but on your data. Make sure that your data is being populating

Comment: How do you enter the values of the fields when the user "edits page" ? Through some HTML fields (i.e. `<input ....>`)?

Comment: why you dont use axios for this requests?

Comment: Thanks I updated the post. I'm not sure why I need axios when dealing with firebase?

Comment: What id the VueEditor component? Also, it is not clear why you don't simply "link" your field and a data item `<b-input v-model="updatedPayload.title"></b-input>`. This way you can populate the field with the existing data from the database and use the value to update the database.